# SQL (Redshift) - Rolling average with all preceding values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table like so:

| Day | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |

How do I create a rolling average that takes into account all previous days to produce a table like so:

| Day | Rolling_avg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3.22 |

Day1 = avg(day 1 values)

Day2 = avg(day1 + day2 values)

Day3 = avg(day1 + day2 + day3 values)

so on so forth..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First aggregate by day to get the sum of values and counts for each day.  Then use analytic functions to find the rolling averages.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Day, SUM(Value) ValueSum, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Day
)

SELECT Day, SUM(ValueSum) OVER (ORDER BY Day) /
                SUM(Count) OVER (ORDER BY Day) AS Rolling_avg
FROM cte
ORDER BY Day;
```

### Demo